# Tuning Lexicon Sentiment-values Using Machine-learning

Tags: machine-learning, python, nltk

I'm constructing a sentiment-analysis model using the lexicon-based approach, and wondering if I can tune the weights of each word-feature in the lexicon using machine-learning. Is this achievable with a machine-learning based tool, or by using an optimisation algorithm such as gridsearch?